# I can't eliminate symbols from a column in a dataset

Tags: r, dataset, symbols

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAvik.png)So I am conducting a data analysis on a dataset about a specific product. This dataset has a few columns one of which is PROD_NAME (Strings) and I have tried to run a code to get rid of symbols like "a1~!@#$%^&*(){}_+:"<>?,./;'[]-=", using the following code:

```
x <- "a1~!@#$%^&*(){}_+:\"<>?,./;'[]-="
str_replace_all(x, "[[:punct:]]", " ")
```

I wanted to get a view of the data by using the command `head()` but the symbols I wanted to get rid of still show up.

I have also tried the following

```
str_replace_all(x, "[^[:alnum:]]", " ")
gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", " ", x)
```

Suggestions will be very much appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected output? If I use `str_replace_all(x, "[^[:alnum:]]", " ")`, the result is `"a1                             "`. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. That is the output I expect however, when I view the data, the symbol still appears.

Comment: Have you assigned the result into the data?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean @Roland

Comment: I think that Rolland was asking if you did something like: x = str_replace_all(x, "[^[:alnum:]]", " "), instead of just calling the function.

Comment: Isn't it redundant?, you are assigning x a command that contains x itself

Comment: No, it is not redundant. You are calling something on `x`, but this does not change `x` itself. You have to assign it back to `x` if you want to store the changes in `x`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have now ran that command but it prompts a + instead of a >, why is this happening? I am sorry for making so many questions but I am new to R

Comment: Changing the prompt from `>` to `+` is R's way of saying that your previous command seems not-closed. Check for hanging (unmatched) parens, braces, brackes, or quotes.

Comment: I still can't seem to fix my issue. I have tried all the suggestions but when I type in "transactionData" (the name of the variable that is connected to the uploaded dataset) it still shows the symbols I'm trying to get rid of. I have added an image for clarity (the blue hyperlink in the main question)

Comment: It appears to me that Bas already answered your question. R (mostly) does not modify objects in place. In other words: most of the time, object are immutable.  Instead, R creates a copy of the modified object which you need to assign to the object name. In your case: `x <- str_replace_all(x, "[^[:alnum:]]", " ")`